# NPM CI and Bluebird promise warnings

Tags: node.js, npm, promise, continuous-integration, bluebird

**Short intro**: We are starting to use npm `ci` for a more reliable installation of dependencies for our react application, instead of `install`. But we have been noticing some strange promise rejection behavior when using `ci`.

---

**Description:**
When running npm `ci` in a node environment with `NODE_ENV` set to `development`, we receive hundreds of promise warnings from the Bluebird promise library:

`(node:95984) Warning: .then() only accepts functions but was passed: [object Object]`

I am curious whether these are coming from npm CI's code itself, as we have never seen these errors except when using npm CI.

You can also see in [their source code](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/latest/lib/ci.js) that NPM is using Bluebird Promise library version `3.5.3`.

To test this, I have incrementally removed all of the main and dev dependencies in our package.json, generating lock files and running `npm ci` to see if it originated from any specific packages, but it occurred every single time down to the last package (and alternate single packages).

I have also created an entirely separate npm repo and installed a package (react-scripts@latest), generated a lock file, and on running `npm ci` received the same promise warnings.

We were able to silence the errors on build by setting the environment variable `BLUEBIRD_PROMISES=0` per the recommendations of this [npm issue](https://npm.community/t/npm-ci-produces-a-tonn-of-excess-warnings-on-install/3261), and this *did* silence the warnings. But we would like to know why this is happening, and if there is something underlying these warnings that deserves more attention than simply silencing them.

**Version info:**
npm: `6.4.1`
node: `10.15.0`

Answer (score 0):

I totally missed this (almost year old) question :]

> But we would like to know why this is happening,

Bluebird has a warning feature where it warns against incorrect usage of promises. NPM uses bluebird internally and NPM has incorrect usage inside its own code base at some places.

The particular [warning](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/warning-explanations.html#warning-.then) happens when you `.then` with a non-function which is likely an error.

> and if there is something underlying these warnings that deserves more attention than simply silencing them.

You can silence them in general with environment variables or safely ignore them.